# Wayfinder, paginator, or breadcrumb?

Tags: breadcrumbs, pagination, definition

I can't seem to find what I need because I am not coming up with the right term.

I've heard one or two people call it a "wayfinder" and I personally call it "breadcrumb", then again "paginator" can also fit the bill.

What I want is the following:

I have a site with a multiple-pages form. I want my users to see the steps through the form. I searched for all three terms and nothing I can use has shown. I could build one from scratch but I am interested in what is out there. Someone may have done a better job than I will be doing.

Any idea on what to call this and if you have a link I can check out, that will be bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the term you're looking for is a [Wizard](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=software%20wizard)?

'Pagination' usually refers to a set of results that are too numerous to display at once (e.g. a search result)

'Breadcrumbs' are specifically navigation links that lead you 'back up the path' (as in Hansel and Gretel) to provide navigational context for each page.

I have not heard of a 'wayfinder'.

Comment: ding ding ding!!!! we have a winner! You got it my friend. Thats it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for or now: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/

It breaks an HTML form into separate parts, and allows users to go through them in pieces. This script also allows you to incorporate form validation as well, and I have used it a few times. It looks pretty good too.

Comment: beautiful form UI/UX but I have that concept. What I am looking for is something I could put on the sidenav that tell the client which page or step into the form they are in. It would actually be awesome if it calculated a percentage of completion